# Pick and Place File with panelized PCB

Tags: pcb, fabrication

I've designed my first PCB that will be machine populated. I sent my design to a fab who is going to panelize and make the bare boards.

I'm using a separate company to populate the boards. Would it be typical if they just wanted the pick and place file I generated for the individual board, or would I have to somehow make one for the whole panel?

Comment: If you have already identified the PCB assembly shop(s), you should simply post this question to them.  They will be impressed by your consideration.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to do the panelization myself. You still have to talk to the board house if you want to optimize the panel size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you send a pick and place file for a single PCB. I hope the board house knows what the assembly house needs for fiducials and tooling holes.

Comment: That said, DON'T forget fiducials!!!